# Can I post an array of files using form/multipart in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

For example: I need to post data in such a format: {imgFiles:[(filename, file), (filename, file), (flename file)]

I have tried to do it like this:

```
pic_array = [
    ('file1', open("somefile.xml", "r")),
    ('file2', open("somefile2.xml", "r"))
]
files_pics = [('imgFiles', pic_array)]

r = requests.post(
    'https://some.site/path/to/api/point',
    data=data_details,
    headers=headers_1,
    files=files_pics
)
print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.json())
```

and get a

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/someusername/PycharmProjects/someprojectname/data_load.py", line 115, in <module>

 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 116, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 316, in prepare
self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 504, in prepare_body
(body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 151, in _encode_files
fn, fp, ft, fh = v
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)
```

Is there any way to post files exactly as array?

Comment: This error message is meaningless without context. Please post the full traceback

Comment: Updated with a full traceback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending multiple files incorrectly see the following working example.  If I take my example and change it to a list like yours I get the same error.

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8080/'
files = {'file':  open('sql.py', 'rb'),
         'file2': open('lst.py', 'rb')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: The point is the server API accepts files ONLY in this format: 
{key1:value1,key2:value2,imgFiles:[(filename,file), (filename2,file2), .., (filenameN,fileN)]}